# Render View inside a layout view in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rendering

I need to make a search form, which will display on all pages, even the error pages, on the top of the page, so i decided to make a view and model for it, and render this view in the main layout.So i have created a simple model:

SearchModel.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class SearchFormModel extends Model
{
    public $query;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

And a view:

```
SearchView.php

<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'search-nav-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-inline ml-3'],
]) ?>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control form-control-navbar', 'placeholder'
    => 'Search'])->label('Search'); ?>

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Which is a search form. Now i have also the main layout:

```
<?php

use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">


    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company <?= date('Y') ?></p>

        <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

What i dont understand is, how i can render my search form from inside my layout view? I need to put it in controller, but controller only gives actions for specific page routes.

**UPDATE**

I got rid of all errors but now the form is just not rendering on the page, there is no form tag even. Here is how i render it inside **main.php**:

```
 $model = new SearchFormModel;
 $this->render('@app/views/site/SearchFormView',['model' => $model]);
```

And i have fixed the model SearchFormModel.php like this:

```
class SearchFormModel extends Model
{

    public $search;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // тут определяются правила валидации
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to `echo $this->render()` not just `$this->render()` or use short-tags if they are available like this `<?=$this->render()?>`

Answer (score 2):

You can render a view inside a layout file using

```
<?= $this->render('//layouts/path/to/view') ?>

<?= $this->render('@app/views/path/to/view') ?>
```

or

```
<?= Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/path/to/view.php'); ?>
```

See DOCS for [**`render()`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-view#render()-detail) and [**`renderFile()`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-view#renderFile()-detail)

Comment: I have tried to render it like this: <?= $this->render('@app/views/SearchFormView') ?>   but i get the error 'view @app/views/SearchFormView require model parameter'

Comment: Also i have tried to do this:    $model = new SearchFormModel;
        $this->render('@app/views/site/SearchFormView',['model' => $model]);  this way i get the error like so: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\SearchFormView::text

Comment: thats a separate thing if you want to pass the model to the `searchFormView` your error tells that your `SearchFormModel` does not have the field `text` @AdeptusAStrates1 , are you sure this field exists in the `SearchFormModel` or the main model from which the searchForm is extended ?

Comment: you are rendering the form field `<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control form-control-navbar', 'placeholder'
    => 'Search'])->label('Search'); ?>` which is raising the error

Answer (score 0):

Render function in Yii2 returns the result of rendering. You have to echo explicitly. Try out instead:

```
$model = new SearchFormModel;
echo $this->render('@app/views/site/SearchFormView',['model' => $model]);
```

Comment: this should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

You should extract your form into widget and use it in your layout. Layouts should be relatively simple, including some external view into it looks like code smell, and creating model inside of view file (including layouts files) is basically a violation of MVP pattern.

Create widget with form:

```
class SearchFormWidget extends \yii\base\Widget {

    public function run() {
        $model = new SearchFormModel();
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->get());
        return $this->render('search-form-widget', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Put view with your form in `widgets/views/search-form-widget.php` (or similar path depending where you put widget class), and use widget inside of layout:

```
<?= SearchFormWidget::widget() ?>
```

In similar way you may use it in any other place. Much more clean and safe approach than including views viles directly.